# Show requests when running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

After upgrading to the latest version of `npm`, the requests are not shown anymore.

```
$ npm --version
1.4.13
```

Now, pretty ASCII animation is displayed when the packages are installed - that I love, but how can I see the requests that are made? I mean these ones:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<package-name>
...
```

Is there any option for `npm install` to enable this feature?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like they have changed default `loglevel`.

```
npm install --loglevel http
```

You can also add this line to your `~/.npmrc`:

```
loglevel = http
```

Note that this is `ini` format. You must add this line at the global section, e.g. at the first line of the file.

More info: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html

Comment: It works, but the docs say that default value for `logLevel` is `"http"`. It's wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. As you know it is quite new change and docs still not updated, like always. Nobody likes to create and update docs =)